# Error 404 error in servets

Tags: tomcat, servlets

So I'm getting this error 404 in a simple hello world servlet program, when I right click on the project name and then run it on tomcat server (in eclipse). However when I right click on servlet file in the project explorer and then run it on the server it runs perfectly well. Why wont it run by using the former procedure? [former procedure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4DFyf.jpg)

[latter procedure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hWfub.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

Error 404 caused when Tomcat is not finding the servlet or path is incorrect. In your screen shot I am seeing `http://localhost:8080/testproject` that displaying 404 error whereas `http://localhost:8080/testproject/World` working.

you are providing directory path but not writing servlet name that causes